# LINQ query on dbset with multiple conditions

Tags: c#, linq

Need to write a query which retrieves records from a dataset where criteria are met.  The dataset has various data items but also contains an ICollection item, which must also be filtered on.

```cs
var result = await _dbContext
    .MyTable
    .Include(a => a.myCollection)
    .Where(a => a.name == name && a.myCollection.Any(a => a.Type == "Customer"))
    .ToListAsync();
```

The Any() is retrieving all records for that particular user where they have an entry in the collection set to "Customer" but also other records that exist in the collection for that user where the type is not set to "Customer". The code should only return records from the collection where the type is set to "Customer".

Comment: There are many questions that in one way or another ask how to do filtered `Include`s. It's not supported. Please look for workarounds, which depend on the EF-version you're using.

Comment: Am I missing something? I don't see the need for `Any`. Could you just do `.Where(a => a.name == name && a.Type == "Customer")`?